# Saving pandas dataframe subsets to xlsx using df.to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I have a csv that I want to break up into individual excel files. When I try the below it is creating the individual files but not filtering. I'm still new to python and I'm guessing I'm missing a line in the for loop that slices the dataframe. Thanks for the help!

```py
import pandas as pd

# pull in csv
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='UTF-8')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.fillna("", inplace = True)

# group by dealer
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Dealer')))

# for loop grouped by dealer
for name in dfs:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(name)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index= False, header= True, sheet_name= 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    print(name + ' file created.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `dfs` is a dictionary you need to iterate over it with `.items()`.
If you iterate over it as you're doing you get only the keys of the dictionary back.

You're currently not creating any new df in the for loop, as you suspected.

Try instead:

```
# for loop grouped by dealer
for name,df in dfs.items():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(name)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    print(name + ' file created.')
```